# Unable to resolve URL locally to several devices

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, domain

I have a domain name attached to a DDNS. It's pointed at my house and I have three systems that are running a web server using the default ports, and two other ports. I used to have AT&T and this was never an issue, but now that I switched to Charter, I seem to not be resolving the domain name correctly on the inside without client modification.

All the ports have been forwarded correctly and I am able to see it on the outside web so that isn't a problem. I just have so many devices that use these systems that attempting to modify them directly has turned to be a nightmare.

For the past two days I have been Googling different methods and I am unable to come up with a solution. I know that I need some kind of DNS server resolution on my side but unsure how to set one up that won't interfere but also allows me to use the same domain for all three systems.

I changed my Router's DNS addresses to first Google then to OpenDNS, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your NAT gateway is not doing NAT Loopback (a.k.a. NAT hairpinning) correctly. See if that's something you can enable on your NAT gateway. If not, see if you can run open source router firmware such as OpenWrt on your router. If that doesn't work, buy a router known to do NAT Loopback correctly, and use that as your NAT gateway instead of your ISP-provided box.

I'm guessing the reason this broke when you switched ISPs is that you use the ISP-provided boxes as your NAT gateway router, and maybe your AT&T box did NAT Loopback correctly, but your Charter box does not.

Your DDNS points your domain name at the external/public/WAN IP address of your router. This means that when a client on the internal/private/LAN side of your router tries to connect to that address, your router has to be smart enough to realize that this packet needs to have outbound NAT done to it, and then have inbound NAT done to it, and then get sent to your internal server. The same with replies from the server to the client. This idea of having to do both kinds of NAT on the same packets is known as NAT loopback or NAT hairpinning because the packets have to make a "hairpin turn" and get looped right back into the router, right back into the private LAN. Many residential broadband gateways are cheap trash that don't do NAT Loopback correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I will look for a router then. Is there a specific one you would recommend or stay away from?

Comment: @HarleyFrank Unfortunately I don't have any to recommend at this time. I've been using Apple's AirPort product line since the beginning and they've always done NAT Loopback right. The 2013 AirPort Extreme 802.11ac is still a nice reliable box for me but it's discontinued at this point. Other than that, I'm partial towards anything that runs OpenWrt well, since OpenWrt has the best bufferbloat protection in the form of Cake (FQ-CoDel), and bufferbloat is a big problem that most router vendors seem to be ignoring.

Comment: Hey @Spiff, I just wanted to let you know that I found a decent Netgear on sale that solved the issue I was having. Thank you for your answer and help. It's appreciated.